# Grouping same neighbours with Kotlin Collections Operations

Tags: kotlin, collections

Which operation from [Kotlin Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-operations.html) would be the most suitable for grouping the same consecutive neighbours in a list?
Let's say we have a list:

```kotlin
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

and I'd like to obtain a list of groups splitted when an item changes (preserving ordering):

```kotlin
[['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['A'], ['B']]
```

It seems to be a common case, so I thought that it must be supported by rich Kotlin Collections operations, but I didn't find anything appropriate there.

I've already tried using `reduce`, `fold` and it all seems not to handle that case at all. 
I think that using `groupBy` is pretty close to desired result:

```kotlin
val chars: List<Char> = "AABBBAB".toList()
val groups = chars.groupBy { char -> char }
    .map { (key, grouped) ->
         grouped
    }
```

It works almost well but it joins same group types together: `[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]`)

I know how to do that using some ugly loops and buffers, but my question is how to achieve that using some fancy Kotlin operations (or combination of them)?

My real case is slightly more complex (I'd like to group some objects by its property in a way described above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I came up with uses MutableLists, which might be what you were describing by "ugly loops and buffers".

```
fun <T, C> Iterable<T>.separateConsecutiveDuplicates(comparisonSelector: (T) -> C): List<List<T>> =
    mutableListOf<Pair<C, MutableList<T>>>().also { lists ->
        forEach {
            val comparison = comparisonSelector(it)
            if (lists.isEmpty() || lists.last().first != comparison)
                lists += comparison to mutableListOf(it)
            else
                lists.last().second += it
        }
    }.map { it.second }
```

If you don't mind the selector being run on each item twice, the code's a little cleaner:

```
fun <T, C> Iterable<T>.separateConsecutiveDuplicates(comparisonSelector: (T) -> C): List<List<T>> =
    mutableListOf<MutableList<T>>().also { lists ->
        forEach {
            if (lists.isEmpty() || comparisonSelector(lists.last().last()) != comparisonSelector(it) )
                lists += mutableListOf(it)
            else
                lists.last() += it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Folding is a way to go:

```
val source = listOf('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B')

source.fold(mutableListOf<MutableList<Char>>()) { sum, c ->
     if (sum.isEmpty() || sum.last().first() != c) {
         // add new group
         sum.add(mutableListOf(c))
     } else {
         // add to the last group
         sum.last().add(c)
     }
     sum
 }
```