# Split a lists into multiple sub lists with predicate - looking for a nice way to write this code

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, data-structures

Lets say I have a list of integers: `[2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2]`, and I want to split this lists into sub lists so each sub list contain values that match the predicate, or if it doesn't then only the value that didn't match, and it should be in the order of the original list.

So for example, if the predicate is "is even" I expect to get the following result:
`[[2, 4, 4, 6],[1],[8],[3, 5],[2, 2, 2]]`

I have a code that works, but it's pretty ugly in my opinion and I feel like there should be a much nicer way to write it:

```kotlin
private fun <T : Any> toSubLists(values: List<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
  val subLists = mutableListOf<List<T>>()
  var currentList = mutableListOf<T>()
  values.forEach {
    if (!predicate(it)) {
      if (currentList.isNotEmpty()) {
        subLists.add(currentList)
        currentList = mutableListOf()
      }
      subLists.add(listOf(it))
    } else {
      currentList.add(it)
    }
  }
  if (currentList.isNotEmpty()) {
    subLists.add(currentList)
  }
  return subLists
}
```

Comment: how do elements like the example land in different sublists when the predicate is `is negative`? All those elements are positive.

Comment: @user1984 i guess he actually meant "is even"

Comment: @IvoBeckers you are correct, `is even` checks out.

Comment: But I think the code should actually say `if (!predicate(it))` if I understand the code and the requirement

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin person, but I guess 2 while loops inside another while loop would give you readable code. I can write out the pseudo code if that helps.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kotlin, but according to its documentation, there is a **groupby** function in its standard library: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html

Comment: Yes, it should be "is even" and '!predicate(it)', edited, thanks!

Comment: @Stef unfortunately `groupBy` will only create 2 groups here, the OP's goal is to only group consecutive elements (a.k.a. "runs")

Comment: @Joffrey Oh! Apologies. In haskell and python, `groupby` only groups consecutive runs, so I assumed it was the same for Kotlin. Although, with a closer look, kotlin's groupby returns a map, not a list of lists, so I should have expected it.

Comment: Similar questions: [Grouping same neighbours with Kotlin Collections Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890244/grouping-same-neighbours-with-kotlin-collections-operations); [Split a list into groups of consecutive elements based on a condition in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355091/split-a-list-into-groups-of-consecutive-elements-based-on-a-condition-in-kotlin)

Comment: @TomerArazy it seems your example result and your code are not in accordance. Which result are you looking for exactly? Should the non-matching elements be grouped together in consecutive runs as well? Or should they each be alone in their list?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's better because it might be harder to understand, but this is a way to do it

```
private fun <T : Any> toSubLists(values: List<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> = 
    values.withIndex().groupBy({
        var index = it.index
        while (index != 0 && predicate(values[index]) && predicate(values[index - 1])) index--
        index
    }){
        it.value
    }.values.toList()
```

see it working [here](https://pl.kotl.in/T_aEG4d3W)

Answer (score 1):

There is [a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8280) for a generic version of this that accepts other key selectors than predicates.

In the meantime, for your use case I think we can simplify a bit:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.groupRunsBy(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<MutableList<T>>()
    var currentlyMatching: Boolean? = null
    forEach {
        val itemMatches = predicate(it)
        if (itemMatches == currentlyMatching) {
            result.last().add(it)
        } else {
            currentlyMatching = itemMatches
            result.add(mutableListOf(it))
        }
    }
    return result
}

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2)
    
    println(list.groupRunsBy { it % 2 == 0 }) // [[2, 4, 4, 6], [1], [8], [3, 5], [2, 2, 2]]
}
```

Tested here: https://pl.kotl.in/OHVr7S6lX

This version can easily be changed to support any selector that returns non-null keys.

Comment: IMHO this solution is not correct (although it gives the same result as the OP states, but that solution is not the one the OPs code delivers). In addition with this answer you'll have the same result for { it % 2 == 0 } and { it % 2 != 0 }.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the requirement, I based it on the OP's example, but you're right the description indeed doesn't seem to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <T : Any> toSubLists(values: List<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
  val items = values.map { predicate(it) to listOf(it) }.toMutableList()
  for (i in items.indices.last downTo 1) {
    if (items[i - 1].first && items[i].first) {
      items[i - 1] = items[i - 1].first to items[i - 1].second + items[i].second
      items.removeAt(i)
    }
  }
  return items.map { it.second }
}

val list1 = listOf(2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2)
val isOdd: (Int) -> Boolean = { it % 2 != 0 }
val isEven: (Int) -> Boolean = { it % 2 == 0 }

println(toSubLists(list1, isOdd))   // [[2], [4], [4], [6], [1], [8], [3, 5], [2], [2], [2]]
println(toSubLists(list1, isEven))  // [[2, 4, 4, 6], [1], [8], [3], [5], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's requirements. Consecutive elements that don't match the predicate are all in single-item lists instead of being together

Comment: You are right when you consult the proposed result of the OP. But when you run the code of the OP the solution I provide is correct ([3] and [5] being separate for isEven).

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <T : Any> toSubLists(values: List<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
  return values
    .map { listOf(predicate(it) to listOf(it)) }
    .reduce { acc, item ->
      if (acc.last().first && item.first().first)
        acc.subList(0, acc.size - 1) + listOf(acc.last().first to acc.last().second + item.first().second)
      else
        acc + item
    }
    .map { it.second }
}

val list1 = listOf(2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2)
val isOdd: (Int) -> Boolean = { it % 2 != 0 }
val isEven: (Int) -> Boolean = { it % 2 == 0 }

println(toSubLists(list1, isOdd))   // [[2], [4], [4], [6], [1], [8], [3, 5], [2], [2], [2]]
println(toSubLists(list1, isEven))  // [[2, 4, 4, 6], [1], [8], [3], [5], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's requirements. Consecutive elements that don't match the predicate are all in single-item lists instead of being together

Comment: You are right when you consult the proposed result of the OP. But when you run the code of the OP the solution I provide is correct ([3] and [5] being separate for isEven).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive recursive solution:

```
fun <E> toSubListsRecursive(
  list: List<E>,
  startIndex: Int = 0,
  accMainList: MutableList<List<E>> = mutableListOf(),
  accSubList: MutableList<E> = mutableListOf(),
  newAccSubListRequired: (Boolean) -> Boolean = { true },
  predicate: (E) -> Boolean
): List<List<E>> =
  if (list.lastIndex < startIndex) {
    accMainList
  } else {
    val currElement = list[startIndex]
    val currPredicateResult = predicate(currElement)
    val currAccSubList =
      if (newAccSubListRequired(currPredicateResult)) mutableListOf(currElement).also(accMainList::add)
      else accSubList.apply { add(currElement) }
    toSubListsRecursive(list, startIndex + 1, accMainList, currAccSubList, { x -> x != currPredicateResult }, predicate)
  }
```

A similar solution adapted to use fold:

```
data class Accumulator<E>(
  var mainList: MutableList<List<E>>,
  var subList: MutableList<E>,
  var newAccSubListRequired: (Boolean) -> Boolean
)

fun <E> toSubListsWithFold(list: List<E>, predicate: (E) -> Boolean): List<List<E>> =
  list.fold<E, Accumulator<E>>(Accumulator(mutableListOf(), mutableListOf()) { true }) { acc, currElement ->
    val currPredicateResult = predicate(currElement)
    val currSubAcc =
      if (acc.newAccSubListRequired(currPredicateResult)) mutableListOf(currElement).also(acc.mainList::add)
      else acc.subList.apply { add(currElement) }
    acc.apply {
      subList = currSubAcc;
      newAccSubListRequired = { x -> x != currPredicateResult }
    }
  }.mainList
```

If the predicate is not expensive you can simplify (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893092/1205299)):

```
fun <E> anotherToSubListWithFold(list: List<E>, predicate: (E) -> Boolean): List<List<E>> =
  list.fold(mutableListOf<MutableList<E>>()) { acc, curr ->
    if (acc.isEmpty() || acc.last().first().let(predicate) != curr.let(predicate)) {
      acc.apply { add(mutableListOf(curr)) }
    } else {
      acc.apply { last().add(curr) }
    }
  }
```